# Hide Place Order button when no shipping options are available

Tags: woocommerce

My woocommerce shop is UK based, selling bulky items to both the UK market and internationally using FedEx.

I use FedEx for international shipping but sometimes an address cannot be shipped to and the customer gets the 'no shipping available' message. However, as far as I can tell, Woocommerce STILL allows the customer to place the order in these situations resulting in an order that cannot be fulfilled. Is there a simple setting somewhere that I am missing that says if no shipping is available, don't let the order be placed?

I did find this resource - https://www.bolderelements.net/support/knowledgebase/removing-checkout-button-shipping-not-available/ but that only removes the ability to get to the checkout page.

It seems like there should be a setting for something this basic?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by not hiding the button, but by forcing an error if there is no shipping. I'm using the woocommerce_checkout_process action for this:

```
function is_valid_shipping() {
    $selected_shipping = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods');
    if(in_array(false, $selected_shipping)){
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Your Shipping is not valid.' ), 'error' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'is_valid_shipping' );
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. It hides the "checkout" button on checkout page if there are no available shipping methods. Goes into your child theme's functions.php.

```
//Hide checkout button if no shipping is available
add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', 'hide_checkout_button__no_shipping_html' );
function hide_checkout_button__no_shipping_html( $button ) {

    $package_counts = array();
    $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
    foreach( $packages as $key => $pkg ) {
        $package_counts[ $key ] = count( $pkg[ 'rates' ] );
    }

    if( in_array( 0, $package_counts ) ) { //no available shipping method
        $button = '';
    }
    return $button;
}
```